# How do I solve this sets equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I calculate all the elements in this equation? 
My problem is with those absolute values, I don't really know to handle them, i'll be happy for some help.

$$\{      x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space\space \mid x-2\mid < 5   \} \cup 
\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space \mid x-4 \mid < 3 \}  $$

Comment: Translate $|x-2|<5$ into $-5<x-2<5$ and work this out. This to get rid of absolute values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space\space \mid x-2\mid < 5\} \cup \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space \mid x-4 \mid < 3 \}=\\
\{x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space\space -5<x-2< 5\} \cup \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space -3<x-4< 3 \}=\\
\{x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space\space -3<x<7\} \cup \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space 1<x<7 \}=\\
\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \space | \space -3<x<7 \}$$

Comment: better to give some hints, rather than giving full answers

Comment: @GA316 If you don't know at all what to do it's better to have a one full example of how you should deal with such questions. At least that's my opinion.

Comment: A full answer is okay, but if you do so then it is better to solve the question for *different* inequalities of the same sort. This to avoide abuse of the site.